# cannot bind the new display member for a combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am confused on how this works,
shouldn't it just display the values inside this ISeq, its receiving the right values at least

```
public ISeq<double> List
{
  set {
    ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(value,null);
    ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value".ToString();
    ComboBox.ValueMember = "value";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are binding to simple types do not use `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. This should do the job:

```
public ISeq<double> List
{
  set 
  {
    ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(value,null);
  }
}
```

those two properties are used when binding to more complex objects with `Properties`.

Comment: oh, the feeling I get whenever I get a simple answer, craaaaap

Answer (score 0):

To bind to something you need to have a get as well as a set